# Creating Progress Gauge in ArcGIS Dashboard

Tags: arcgis-online, operations-dashboard

How do I create this kind of Progress Gauge (below) in ArcGIS Dashboard?

[image: Progress Gauge]

Comment: Have you tried reading the help file? Info on dashboard gauge [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/dashboards/get-started/gauge.htm) and how to set up a dashboard [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/dashboards/get-started/create-a-dashboard.htm)?

Comment: Thanks so much. I've read that documentation in the past but doesn't have much on the configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the settings for a similar gauge, in a Classic Dashboard:
[image]

Note the font is simply set to a white color so it fades into the background.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll definitely try it out

Comment: This worked just fine. I never though of it that way until you mentioned it. Thaks

Comment: @Godofsix, you can accept this as the expected answer:)